# Issue with multipart/form-data, ajax and textarea with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce, textarea, multipartform-data

I'm working with html/php/ajax/jquery and today I pointed out a little issue that is driving me crazy.

I've got an html form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" action="">
    <label class="form-label">Nome</label>
    <input name="nome" type="text" class="form-control"><br>
    <label class="form-label">Descrizione</label>
    <textarea name="descrizione" id="text-editor" placeholder="" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
    <label class="form-label">Stato</label>
    <select name="stato" id="source" style="width:30%">
        <option value="1">Abilitato</option>
        <option value="0">Disabilitato</option>
    </select>
    <h4>Foto profilo</h4>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20400000" >  
    <input style="border:0px;" type="file" name="user_foto" id="file"> 
    <div class="form-actions">  
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-cons"><i class="icon-ok"></i>Inserisci</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-cons" onclick="window.location.href='index.php'">Indietro</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm working with a JQuery+Ajax script that is able to fire a php script without reloading page, and insert form's data into a table in my database:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
        var formData = new FormData(this);      
        $.ajax({
            url:'inserisciProfessionisti.php',
            data: formData,
            type:'POST',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
                window.location = 'listaProfessionisti.php'
            },
            error:function(data){}
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
});
```

Here my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
if(!isset($_SESSION['mail'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}
include("include/connect.php");
$conn=mysql_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD);
$db_ok=mysql_select_db($DB, $conn);
$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$descrizione = $_POST['descrizione'];
....
$comando="INSERT INTO professionisti('nome','descrizione',...)VALUES('$nome','$descrizione',...)";
$ris=mysql_query($comando, $conn) or die("Errore connessione database: " . mysql_error());
...
```

Everything works like a charm apart textarea content. It seems that textarea content wouldn't be passed to my php script.

Comment: `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);` is the same as `var formData = new FormData(this);`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I fix it but the issue persists.

Comment: First of all, validate your HTML. `button` can not be a descendant of an `a` element, and you have unclosed `div` elements in there as well.

Comment: it seems to be fine - http://i.imgur.com/iogJpLI.jpg

Comment: I validated HTML. The issue persists again.

Comment: I'm testing it using http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bt89W/1/ - here the request data contains the value of the textarea, can you check your request using browser developer tools... also check how you are reading the value in your PHP

Comment: I've updated my question with php code. It seems to be correct but the issue persists. Talking about textarea, I'm using TinyMCE.

Comment: I pointed out that It works, without submitting form using ajax function. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue solved. 
I add this `onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(true,true);"` to submit `button` and everything works like a charm. 
I think It should be a tinyMCE bug.

Comment: Just to let users know: the "bug" is still there in 2019, so this one-line life saviour is still needed :-)

Comment: In 2022 as well. This resolution is as valid as ever.